# Upgrading NPM on a single git branch

Tags: npm

I want to upgrade NPM on a project im working on, but I not sure the best way to go about it.

Can NPM be upgraded on a single git branch? Or if it has to be upgraded globally, can it affect any of the packages and break anything?

Comment: npm is installed globally because node.js is installed globally.

Comment: You could try to work with a node version manager. As stated "Node version managers allow you to install and switch between multiple versions of Node.js and npm on your system so you can test your applications on multiple versions of npm" (from https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm)